# Правильно підключіть jQuery до HTML сторінки, використовуючи CDN (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js). Помогите пожалуйста с заданием!

Tags: html, jquery, cdn

Вивчаємо Javascript

```
<body>
    <p>jQuery - популярна JavaScript-бібліотека з відкритим кодом.
    </p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("p").css({color:"red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<p>jQuery - популярна JavaScript-бібліотека з відкритим кодом.
</p>
```